# What's wrong with my using argc/argv this way in c?

Tags: c, argument-passing, winmain

This works:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
....
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
....
```

But this doesn't:

```
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE p1, HINSTANCE p2, LPSTR argv, int argc) { 
....
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
....
```

Can someone point out what's wrong there?

Comment: What's the error? Compile time? What is the signature of gtk_init()?

Comment: gtk_init() works in the first example.

Answer (score 5):

WinMain does not provide you with argc and argv - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559%28VS.85%29.aspx. You get the command line as a single string (the third parameter) which you have to parse yourself.

Comment: Oh,that's awful to have to parse myself.